# ruby rails - suggestion list for text fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any feature or Gem in rails 3+ for suggestion list for completing text fields? 
Something like google instant search, give a drop down of matching entries based on typed keywords in the text field. The function shall make an ajax call and retrieve relative values from back end database or some other source etc. I don't have a code right now, I was guessing it would be observe a field and make ajax call based on that. Is there any better sophisticated way?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Check out ryan bates [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association) on auto completion. Think this is what you're looking for